# Android Volley Image Caching Different Size Bitmaps

Tags: android, image, caching, bitmap, android-volley

I am currently using Volley Image Loader to load and cache images in my app.  The caching works correctly, but I am seeing that when I try to load the same network image into a different sized ImageView, the cache will not get hit.  I believe this is because getCacheKey in ImageLoader appends the size of the bitmap to the key:

```
private static String getCacheKey(String url, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    return (new StringBuilder(url.length() + 12)).append("#W").append(maxWidth).append("#H").append(maxHeight).append(url).toString();
}
```

How do I save the image that Volley is downloading and use that for all the different sizes I require instead of having to make another network request for the same image but of a different size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you load an image without using NetworkedImageView then the image loaded will be the full image.  So instead of using a NetworkedImageView I loaded the image like this:

```
getImageLoader().get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                ((ImageView)view).setLocalImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });
```

This will load the Image with a key of #W0#H0.  This will lose some speed because the ImageView will have to do work to resize the image, but now we do not have to make network requests for the same Image.

Comment: You can do this in a simpler way:
imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, defaultDrawable, errorDrawable));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `NetworkedImageView`, Volley will only hit the L1 cached image for a URL if both layout params are set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, or the width and height of the view are exactly the same as one fetched from previously. One way to get around this is to ignore the width and height:

```
private static String getCacheKey(String url, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

  return (new StringBuilder(url.length() + 12)).append(url).toString();
}
```

Another method would be to create your own subclass of NetworkedImageView that sets maxWidth and maxHeight to 0 before requesting.